# Running a remote PowerShell script with a Git command in it results in NativeCommandError

Tags: windows, git, powershell

I am getting an error while executing a remote PowerShell script. From my local machine I am running a PowerShell script that uses `Invoke-Command` to `cd` into a directory on a remote Amazon Windows Server instance, and a subsequent `Invoke-Command` to execute script that lives on that server instance. The script on the server is trying to git clone a repository from GitHub. I can successfully do things in the server script like "ls" or even "git --version". However `git clone`, `git pull`, etc. result in the following error:

> Cloning into 'MyRepo'... + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (Cloning into 'MyRepo'...:String) [], RemoteException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

This is my first time using PowerShell or a Windows Server. Can anyone provide some direction on this problem.

The client script:

```
$s = new-pssession -computername $server -credential $user
invoke-command -session $s -scriptblock { cd C:\Repos; ls } 
invoke-command -session $s -scriptblock { param ($repo, $branch) & '.\clone.ps1' -repository $repo -branch $branch} -ArgumentList $repository, $branch
exit-pssession
```

The server script:

```
param([string]$repository = "repository", [string]$branch = "branch")
git --version
start-process -FilePath git -ArgumentList ("clone", "-b $branch    https://github.com/MyGithub/$repository.git") -Wait
```

I've changed the server script to use start process and it is no longer throwing the exception.  It creates the new repository directory and the .git directory but doesn't write any of the files from the github repository.  This smells like a permissions issue.  Once again invoking the script manually (remote desktop into the amazon box and execute it from powershell) works like a charm.

Comment: Can you show the lines of script with the Invoke-Command?  You should be invoking it with the -Session parameter.

Comment: Update:  including the scripts

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Anytime you're calling an external executable from PowerShell, I highly recommend using `Start-Process`. The `Start-Process` cmdlet handles command line arguments much better, as compared to calling the executables directly.

**Important**: You must also be aware that if you run two separate `Invoke-Command` commands (unless you're using the `-Session` parameter) that you will be operating in two completely distinct PowerShell Remoting sessions! If you use the `cd` (aka. which is an alias for `Set-Location`) command, the results of that command will not persist into the new session when you run your `Git` command.

```
$GitExe = '{0}\path\to\git.exe' -f $env:SystemDrive;
$ArgumentList = 'clone "c:\path\with spaces\in it"';
Start-Process -FilePath $GitExe -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Wait -NoNewWindow;
```

There is also a `-WorkingDirectory` parameter on the `Start-Process` cmdlet, that allows you to specify the Working Directory for a process. Instead of using the `Set-Location` cmdlet to set the "current directory" of the PowerShell session, you're probably better off specifying the full path to the working directory for the process. For example, let's say you had a Git repository in `c:\repos\repo01`, and your Git exe was in `c:\git`. You shouldn't worry so much about where PowerShell's "current directory" is, and rather focus on specifying the full paths to:

1. The Git executable
2. The Git repositories

Here's an example of how to achieve that:

```
Start-Process -FilePath c:\git\git.exe -ArgumentList 'clone "c:\repos\repo01" "c:\repos\repo02"" -Wait -NoNewWindow;
```

**Note**: I don't know the Git commands, but you should be able to adjust the value of the `$ArgumentList` variable above, to make it work for you. In PowerShell, you can put double-quotes inside of single-quotes, without having to worry about escaping them.

Comment: You can use two separate instances of `Invoke-Command` and have the session be retained if you use `New-PSSession` and pass the resulting session object into the `Invoke-Command -session $sess` parameter.

Comment: Right, but that is not how he's calling it, if he's brand new to PowerShell, I'm guessing. Either way, the current working directory is not of much concern in this case. Full paths will be more reliable.

Comment: I suspect you're right but since the OP hasn't shown the full invocation of Invoke-Command you don't know for sure.  That aside, your comment that "if you run two separate Invoke-Command commands, that you will be operating in two completely distinct PowerShell Remoting sessions" is misleading.  Two different sessions will most definitely NOT be used if the Invoke-Command is invoked with a PSSession object.  Just wanted to point out that you should consider qualifyint that statement.

Comment: Updated answer with qualification. Thanks for pointing that out.